# Accessing gmail from nodejs returns only message id

Tags: node.js

I keep trying to get the information for my messages, but I only get the id; the rest is undefined:

```
function list(auth) {
    var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
    gmail.users.messages.list({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        var messages = response.messages;
        if (messages.length == 0) {
            console.log('No messages found.');
        } else {
            console.log('messages:');
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                var message = messages[i];
                console.log('- '+ message.id +'   '+ message.threadId);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(message)` right before your console.log() with message.id and show what you're getting?

Comment: i only ge those two when i type message what i'm looking for is what am i missing to print out more data as for the message representation in the gmail api is this    :

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource